# Cannot update to Angular2 RC @angular@2.0.0-rc.1

Tags: npm, angular

I am getting the following error when I am trying to upgrade angular2 to RC. JWT is having dependencies on RC, so I had to update to @angular

```
M:\workspace\Angular2StartKit>npm install
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install M:\workspace\Angular2StartKit\@angular@2.0.0-rc.1
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\manish\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
npm ERR! path M:\workspace\Angular2StartKit\@angular@2.0.0-rc.1
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'M:\workspace\Angular2StartKit\@angular@2.0.0-rc.1'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'M:\workspace\Angular2StartKit\@angular@2.0.0-rc.1'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! M:\workspace\Angular2StartKit\npm-debug.log
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {  
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.1",  
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.12",  
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",  
    "cors": "^2.7.1",  
    "es6-promise": "3.0.2",  
    "es6-shim": "0.33.3",  
    "express": "4.13.3",  
    "express-jwt": "^3.4.0",  
    "gulp-concat": "2.6.0",  
    "material-design-lite": "^1.1.3",  
    "mongodb": "^2.1.16",  
    "mongoose": "^4.4.12",  
    "promise": "^7.1.1",  
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",  
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",  
    "systemjs": "0.19.16",  
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"  
    }`
```

Comment: Just see the line no 12 Error: no such file or directory.. one might compare pacages from angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html  or might be  M:\workspace\Angular2StartKit path issue

Comment: From docs for rc1: Verify that you are running node `v5.x.x` and npm `3.x.x` by running node -v and npm -v in a terminal/console window. Older and newer versions produce errors.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular2 RC1, there are a set of sub packages you need to specify in your `package.json` file not a big package like with Beta versions:

```
{
  (...)
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    (...)
  }
}
```

Comment: Which would mean I have to change all the imports across my files ... sigh

Comment: You use Angular2 beta1 in your package.json file?

Comment: yes..that's correct. I changed it back to beta as RC was causing issues. I will try your suggestion of including all the packages separately.

Comment: Moving back to beta.17 might be a better option than beta.1. There have been many changes across the beta versions which will mean updating to future rc versions will be more difficult if you go all the back to 1.

Comment: Yes agreed! beta17 should be closer to rc than beta1. The package renaming is done between beta and rc... So you will have nethertheless impacts for sure.